# Install universal Windows 10 apps to specific folder on a drive or remove app shortcuts from start menu WITHOUT removing the app

Tags: windows, hard-drive, xbox360

In Windows 10 currently you can specify **a drive** to install all new apps to and it puts them all in a hidden or protected folder (i believe Program Files/Windows Apps) usually i have no issue with this but since using game pass i'd like to store my games on the hard drive i specifically have for games, which i can do by changing the default drive but my issues with this are.

1) Games & Apps are not treated as different, meaning all my apps would go on my game drive, not just my games

2) It creates multiple 'Windows Apps' folders on the drive, ruining my folder structure.

So i'm curious, is there anything i can do to force new apps to go into a specific folder of my choosing or for the default windows apps folders to go into a specific folder on a drive?

Also, is it possible to remove shortcuts for apps from the start menu, without removing the app itself?

Comment: You could try to leave the apps & games where they are and move each game manually to a place where you want it. Then create a directory softlink using `mklink /D oldDir newDir` at the place where the directory was. The softlink points to the folder where you moved the game to. From Windows perspective everything looks as it was but the game is now on a different drive.

Comment: Apps (including Windows apps) are store in Program Files and data should not be there at all (best practice).  So your data and document organization should not be affected by Windows apps. My structure is organized this way.